# Why the outputs are "X"

Tags: timing

I've been trying to simulate my code (there is no error in synthesis or implement steps and timing constraint is also met) but the output is shown "X" and the process is over before all inputs being read. I cannot figure out why?!
Here is my code for calculating correlation:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity corr_1 is

    generic( N : integer := 4;   -- N is the width of each input symbpl of the signals
                M : integer := 4);  -- M is the length of chosen part of the signals to be correlated(indicating iteration) 

    port( clk : in std_logic;
            xr,xi : in std_logic_vector( N-1 downto 0);  -- real and imaginary N_bit symbol of the first signal
            yr,yi : in std_logic_vector( N-1 downto 0);  -- real and imaginary N_bit symbol of the second signal
            rr_0 : out std_logic_vector(N+N+2 downto 0); -- real part of the output correlation with lag=0
            ri_0 : out std_logic_vector(N+N+2 downto 0); -- imaginary part of the output correlation with lag=0
            rr_1 : out std_logic_vector(N+N+2 downto 0); -- real part of the output correlation with lag=1
            ri_1 : out std_logic_vector(N+N+2 downto 0)  -- imaginary part of the output correlation with lag=1
            );

end corr_1;

architecture hard_arch of corr_1 is
    signal Nyi,Cyi : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);                         --signals used to conjugate the second signal
    signal yi_c : signed(N-1 downto 0);                                      --signals used to conjugate the second signal
    signal yr_d,yi_d : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);                      --delayed signals used to do correlation with lag=1
    signal temr_0,temi_0,temr_1,temi_1 : std_logic_vector(N+N downto 0); --midterm signals for accumulator
    signal Srr_0,Srr_1,Sri_0,Sri_1 : signed(N+N+2 downto 0) :=(others=>'0');--midterm signals for accumulator
    signal counter_0 : integer range 0 to M;                             --counter with initial value of 0
    signal counter_1 : integer range 0 to M;                            --counter with initial value of 0  


-- component declaration (as we are using complex multiplier)
    component cmux_m1 
        port (ar,ai : in std_logic_vector( N-1 downto 0);
                br,bi : in std_logic_vector( N-1 downto 0);
                pr,pi : out std_logic_vector( N+N downto 0)
               );
    end component;      
begin

-- conjugating process using two's complement for the imaginary part of the second input signal
    process(clk)
        begin
            Nyi<= not yi;
            yi_c<=signed(Nyi);
            if rising_edge(clk) then
                Cyi<=std_logic_vector(yi_c + 1);          --now conjugated signal is ready to be used   
            end if;
    end process;

-- delaying our second signal to prepare for correlation with lag=1 
    process(clk)
        begin
            if rising_edge(clk) then
                yr_d<=yr;
                yi_d<=Cyi;
            end if;
    end process;    

-- calculating correlation with lag=0
    cmult_unit_0 : cmux_m1  
        port map(ar=>xr, ai=>xi, br=>yr, bi=>Cyi, pr=>temr_0, pi=>temi_0);
    process(clk,xr,yr)
        begin           
            if counter_0 < M then
                if rising_edge(clk) then
                    Srr_0<= signed(temr_0) + Srr_0;
                    Sri_0<= signed(temi_0) + Sri_0;
                    rr_0<=std_logic_vector(Srr_0);
                    ri_0<=std_logic_vector(Sri_0);
                    counter_0<=counter_0 + 1;
                end if;
            elsif counter_0=M then
                Srr_0<=(others=>'0');
                Sri_0<=(others=>'0');
                rr_0<=(others=>'0');
                ri_0<=(others=>'0');
            end if;

    end process;
-- calculating correlation with lag=1
    cmult_unit_1 : cmux_m1 
        port map(ar=>xr, ai=>xi, br=>yr_d, bi=>yi_d, pr=>temr_1, pi=>temi_1);
    process(clk,xr,yr)
        begin
            if counter_1 < M then
                if rising_edge(clk) then
                    Srr_1<= signed(temr_1) + Srr_1;
                    Sri_1<= signed(temi_1) + Sri_1;
                    rr_1<= std_logic_vector(Srr_1);
                    ri_1<= std_logic_vector(Sri_1);
                    counter_1<= counter_1 + 1;
                end if;
            elsif counter_1=M then
                Srr_1<=(others=>'0');
                Sri_1<=(others=>'0');
                rr_1<=(others=>'0');
                ri_1<=(others=>'0');
          end if;   

    end process;        

end hard_arch;
```

In simulation after four rising edges as the counter equals the M the output is set to zero but it doesn't work for the period before that.

Comment: Have you considered X to be Don't Care value?

Comment: It is in green wave but when I change the clk period for a longer duration and  inputs are waiting for half of it, in simulation the outputs are U for first, then they become zero and next, X but this time in RED.

Comment: Are you using Quartus by any chance?

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm new to VHDL and using ISE.

Comment: Hello, been digging around and found [this](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Simulation-and-Verification/Xilinx-ISE-Simulator-assigns-X-value-to-the-output/td-p/29425) in the Xilinx forums, it deals with your kind of issue.

Comment: I'll check that. Thanks